# Amazon RDS database across application environments

Tags: mysql, security, amazon-web-services, synchronization, amazon-rds

I have three different application environments: production, demo, and dev. In each, I have an RDS instance running MySQL. I have five tables that house data that needs to be the same across all environments. I am trying to find a way to handle this.

For security purposes, it's not best to allow demo and dev to access the production database, so putting the data there seems to be a bad idea.

All environments need read/write capabilities. Is there a good solution to this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> For security purposes, it's not best to allow demo and dev to access the production database, so putting the data there seems to be a bad idea.

Agreed. Do not have your demo/dev environments access data from your production environments.

I don't know your business logic, but I cannot think of a case where dev/demo data needs to be "in sync" with production data, unless the dev/demo environment is also dependent on other "production assets". If that were the case, I would suggest duplicating that data into your other environments.

Usually, the data in your database would be dependent on the environment it's contained within.

For best security and separation of concerns, keep your environment segregated as much as possible. This includes (but not limited to):

- database data,
- customer data,
- images and other files

If data needs to be synchronized, create a script/program to perform that synchronization completely (db + all necessary assets). But do that as part of your normal development pipeline so it goes through dev+testing+qa etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Matt. The data in question are templates. We have been using three separate DB's for this, but we need to keep some entry ID's the same across all instances while allowing new entries across all environments. Development can occur around a set of ID's and those need to be consistent. 

Do you think a master/slave set up would work for the syncing? The hard part would be forcing the modifications to be sent downwards prior to development.

Answer (score 0):

So the thing about RDS and database level access is that you still would manage the user credentials like you would on premise. From an AWS perspective all you would need to do to allow access is update the security groups of your Mysql RDS instances to allow the traffic, then give your application the credentials you have provisioned for it. **I do agree it is bad practice to give production level access to your dev or demo environments.**

As far as the data being the same you can automate a nightly snapshot of the Production database and recreate new instances based on that. If your infrastructure is in Cloudformation or Terraform you can provide the new endpoint created in the snapshot and spin up a new DEV or DEMO environment.

> Amazon RDS creates a storage volume snapshot of your DB instance, backing up the entire DB instance and not just individual databases. You can create a DB instance by restoring from this DB snapshot. When you restore the DB instance, you provide the name of the DB snapshot to restore from, and then provide a name for the new DB instance that is created from the restore. You cannot restore from a DB snapshot to an existing DB instance; a new DB instance is created when you restore.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateSnapshot.html

Comment: Right. Given the other environments access is easy enough, but the idea of lower access is not.

This sounds like a master/slave approach where we would have to push Production down to the other environments. This may work, though it is not desired since I really want co-masters. Unfortunately (I don't even know if it's feasible), RDS controls access based on instance and not individual DB.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a fan out system at the point of data capture, along with a snapshot.

Take a point in time snap shot (i.e. now), spin up test/dev databases from this, and then use SQS->SNS->SQS fan out architecture to push any new changes to the data to your other databases?

Comment: I don't know much about the fan out architecture, but it seems like you could have issues with ID's not matching across DB's for the "same" entry.